# This code is running perfectly in jupyter but not in python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, data-science

It generates an error {{import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'}}

```
import datetime as dt  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
from matplotlib import style  
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web  
style.use('ggplot')
start = dt.datetime(2000, 1, 1)  
end = dt.datetime(2016, 12, 31)  
df = web.DataReader('TSLA', "yahoo", start, end)  
print(df.head())
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `matplotlib` module, do:

```
$pip3 install matplotlib
```